# What's the result of stacking ND filters in terms of total stops?

Tags: exposure, filters, neutral-density, filter-stacking

If you stack two 3-stop neutral density filters, does it reduce the exposure by 6 stops or 9 stops?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's six.

Remember, the stops are *already* logarithmic. That is, a 3-stop reduction (as from a 3-stop ND filter) is a 2³× loss of light — ¹⁄₈ of the light gets through. A one stop filter halves light, since 2¹ is just 2 (→ ¹⁄₂), and two stop filter is 2² (→ ¹⁄₄ the light). When you stack them together, you're adding the exponents, so 2³ stacked with 2³ is 2⁶ — or ¹⁄₆₄th the light. That's the same as thinking "three stops is one over 2³, or ¹⁄₈, and ¹⁄₈ × ¹⁄₈ = ¹⁄₆₄ — which is one over 2⁶".

But, fortunately (and in fact partly why it's *done* that way), you don't have to remember all this. Just remember that 2³ × 2³ = 2⁶ — or, **3 stops plus 3 stops is 6 stops.**

Of course, this is just the math. In the real world, there may be other practical effects, like vignetting in the corners (due to the increased thickness) or color casts — you're adding more layers for the light to go through, and that takes a toll on image quality. See the comments below.

Comment: +1 but you could have summed up as 6!

Comment: @mattdm - The kernel of your answer always comes in the last sentence or two. Maybe a little bold highlighting or people who skim for the short version?

Comment: But the site doesn't take one-character answers. :)

Comment: You forgot to explain the law of stackability failure ;) Two 3-stop ND filters = 6-stops, but three 3-stop filters equals 9-stops in the center and 10-stops along the edges due to vignetting.

Comment: Excellent! To quote Mr. Burns.

Comment: Be careful though. Cokin ND filters give a colour cast when you stack them, as I found out to my cost!

Comment: This is all very helpful, thank you all!  And specifically to Nick Miners, this was actually in reference to some cheap Cokin filters I picked up just to play around with, so that's good to know!

Comment: Bring back high school math+physics all over again, good explanation!

Comment: 2³ + 2³ = 16. which is 2^4. Your math is wrong. if you meant 2^3 x 2^3 then it is 2^6.

Comment: @Ken — fixed. I was improperly using "+" to mean the colloquial "in combination with", and should have used a multiplication sign when writing it in equation form.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @mattdm's answer - the result of stacking ND filters can also be vignetting.